# IAM Policy using Condition ec2:ResourceTag not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have n x EC2 instances that I wish to limit ec2 actions to instances with the same key/value tag (I.E. platform=dev).

I'm looking at doing this using an IAM Policy attached to the group their default IAM user is in.

Policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/tag:platform": "dev"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

I set this up as per the online AWS docs: [Example Policies for Working With the AWS CLI or an AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html)

I check it in the Policy Simulator and it works as expected (pass in a dev and it's allowed, otherwise denied).

Then on one of the servers with the tag key/pair of platform=dev, I run `aws ec2 describe-instances` I get the response:

```
An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

but if I remove the Condition it works. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that not every API Action & Resource will accept the ec2:ResourceTag/tag in the condition.

I think you're probably granting overly-broad permissions (Action: ec2:*), so figure out what actions your instances will need do, and then decide how to restrict them.

The list of actions, resources and conditions keys can be found at [Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've only been testing with this. I have the specific activities tested & working without the condition. By working with this, I was assuming that I was reducing the factors that could be wrong, but as per the other answer, this is not something I can rely on being true (the condition might only work with more specific action/resource definitions).

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this issue before, it had something to do with combining wildcards and conditions. What solved it for us was being more explicit on the action (e.g `["ec2:DescribeInstances"]`), and on the resource as well (`arn:aws:ec2:region:accountid:instance/*`).

Comment: Thanks - between both your answers I got it.